# Can a PHP imagick iterator modify a separate imagick modifier?

Tags: php, imagick

I want to modify 2 imagick objects from the same iterator eg using the docs example

```
$imagick = new \Imagick(realpath($imagePath));
$imagick2 = clone $imagick;
$imageIterator = new \ImagickPixelIterator($imagick);

/* Loop through pixel rows */
foreach ($imageIterator as $pixels) { 
    /* Loop through the pixels in the row (columns) */
    foreach ($pixels as $column => $pixel) { 
        /** @var $pixel \ImagickPixel */
        if ($column % 2) {
            /* Paint every second pixel black*/
            $pixel->setColor("rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)");
        } else {
            //do something to $imagick2 here 
            $pixel->setColor("rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)");
        }
    }

    /* Sync the iterator, this is important to do on each iteration */
    $imageIterator->syncIterator();
```

is this possible and what would the syntax look like?

Answer (score 0):

The iterators are standard PHP iterators, so the can be iterated through manually using the function `next()` and `current()` and checking that it is still valid with `valid()`.

So something like this 'should' work.

```
$imagick = new \Imagick(realpath($imagePath));
$imagick2 = clone $imagick;
$imageIterator1 = new \ImagickPixelIterator($imagick);
$imageIterator2 = new \ImagickPixelIterator($imagick2);

$imageIterator2->reset(); //make sure iterator is at the start.

/* Loop through pixel rows */
foreach ($imageIterator1 as $pixelRow1) { 

    if (!$imageIterator2->valid()) {
        // need to check validity when iterating manually
        break;
    }

    $pixelRow2 = $imageIterator2->current();
    /* Loop through the pixels in the row (columns) */

    foreach ($pixelRow1 as $column => $pixel1) { 
        /** @var $pixel \ImagickPixel */
        if ($column % 2) {
            /* Paint every second pixel black*/
            $pixel1->setColor("rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)");
        }
        else{
            $pixel2 = $pixelRow2[$column];
            //do something to $imagick2 here 
            $pixel2->setColor("rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)");
        }

        $count++;
    }

    $imageIterator2->next();
    /* Sync the iterator, this is important to do on each iteration */
    $imageIterator1->syncIterator();
    $imageIterator2->syncIterator();
}
```